# Setting up facebook App for iOS in Flutter with CocoaPods or FacebookSDK?

Tags: flutter, firebase, facebook, dart

I am trying to set up [flutter_facebook_login](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_facebook_login) plugin to work with my flutter app via firebase.

In the iOS section, the readme states

> This assumes that you've done the "Register and Configure Your App with Facebook" step in the Facebook Login documentation for the iOS site.

When trying to set up my Development Environment I get the choice to either use CocoaPods or Facebook SDK.

[image: dev env]

Which one should I choose, and do I need to follow the install process stated there as well? (pod install in case of CocoaPods)

Comment: in my working project, I chose `SDK: FB SDK`

Comment: did you had to download sdk and follow the steps next when you selected FB SDK or you just entered app details like bundle identifier?

Comment: no, I just add package `flutter_facebook_login`